# avoiding making all your characters sound the same

Tags: dialogue

We surely all have little quirks to our speech. Like my daughter once criticized my writing for using the word "surely" too much. (See, I used it on this post.)

So how do you keep all your characters from sounding the same in dialog? That is, how do you keep them all from sounding just like the writer? It's easy to say, "Pay attention and be careful", but ... pay attention to what? Okay, in my case I've got my eye out for the word "surely". But what else?

There are some obvious extremes. You can make the scientist use a lot of technical language. A 5-year-old should normally talk like a 5-year-old and not like a college professor. In the story I'm working on right now I have a character who lives in another country and who would likely not use English much, so I put some grammar errors into his speech. Etc. Maybe you could give a character some stock phrases that he always uses: "Elementary, my dear Watson", "To the Bat Cave, Robin", etc. But I'd think there are limits to how far you can go with such things without it sounding too gimicky.

Any tips?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On top of what others gave as excellent advices on getting "in the mind of a character" let me add a few crutchy "dialects" you can give your characters.

- The speaker is using Learner's English. The language is correct, but simple. The sentences are short. Correct sentence structure is used, where native speakers use clauses. The speaker avoids complex constructs. Their list of words is limited. Sometimes the speaker uses words that marginally apply and look awkward.
- Archaic. The person has learnt English from KJV Bible foremost, and is currently striving with proper, modern English.
- Rapid fire speaker speaks in rapid sentences, and abuses conjunctions, like when the message is completed, the person must digress and keep talking about something barely related but this is how one builds the character, isn't it? And the digressions contain random weirdness, and hidden plot clues, or non-sequiturs, which may be funny, or just weird and the style is annoying at times but memorable and energetic, and some love it...
- Laid back. Speaking is a tiring activity. So... Sparsely. Only essentials. Frequent pauses... no? Well... Pauses are good. Sit back and enjoy. It will be fine.
- Concrete. Military style, sir. No redundancies, no ambiguities and only regular amount of courtesy, sir. Reporting facts, staying on topic and hiding emotions. Respectful, but firm.
- Uh... a recluse? Forgetful? Not used to all that... communication. All harder words are there... but building sentences takes... um, effort? Time? These... whatdyacallem... interjections happen often.
- Slangs. I'll skip examples.
- A classy language. You should not use crude contractions. Choosing fabulous flourishes of the language will give aura of elegance, but it is a clear sign of an uncouth upstart to abuse some *verbiage* where cultured but common words suffice.

You should develop more original and closer to "generic" styles for the main cast, but these are very nice to give some secondary characters some depth and character at low cost.

Comment: I just registered to upvote this post, because I enjoyed it.

Comment: Oh, how I love your explanations!

Comment: Dude you're a master

Comment: I would avoid slang when possible as it comes off as "Totally Radical, Dude" when tried, acording to Tvtropes article.   That said, keep in mind some slang has been around for a long time.  Wikipedia has a wonderful time line that shows the use of the word "cool" as in stylish has been in U.S. Vernacular dating back to the 1600s.  And  I once pointed out to a roleplay group who's story was set in 1899 that calling a cop a "Pig" shouldn't be used then because in 1899, that was your grandpa's slang (it wouldn't come back until the 1960s).

Comment: I would also add that if you have a British and American character, try and show off that the Brit speaks with the "British Spelling" of the words while the American uses the "American Spelling" in his dialog.

Comment: @hszmv Oh, that largely depends on *what* slang you use. “Our pockets were full of deng, so there was no real need from the point of view of crasting any more pretty polly to tolchock some old veck in an alley and viddy him swim in his blood while we counted the takings and divided by four, nor to do the ultra-violent on some shivering starry grey-haired ptitsa in a shop and go smecking off with the till’s guts.” -  ‘A Clockwork Orange’

Comment: @SF. Or the use of "whelmed" in Young Justice (Robin had a dislike of words with prefixes when the unprefixed version was not used in vernacular.  "Whelmed" is an actual word and does mean the opposite of overwhelmed.   Astor is not the opposite of disastor, but he mad it a word anyway.).

Comment: @hszmv On a side track, but yeah, I'm always amused by "un-" style words where we never used the positive version. Like if a cruel person is "ruthless", then is a compassionate person "ruthful"? Etc.

Comment: @hszmv RE British vs American: Sure, and there are many cases of different words in the two dialects. I saw a mystery story once where a British character said, "I have to make a long-distance call to my lawyer", and I thought, wouldn't a British person say "solicitor"? As it turned out that was deliberate. In the end the Brilliant Detective reveals that that statement tipped him off that this person was really an American impersonating whoever it was he claimed to be, because, the detective said, a Briton would have said "I have to make a trunk call to my solicitor."

Comment: @SF Slang gets dated very quickly. The slang that would make you sound trendy and contemporary when I was a boy in the 1960s is mostly not in use today, and if you used it, people would say,  "Wow, he sounds like he's from the 60s. Groovy, baby." I suppose if you're story is firmly set in a particular time period, using slang from that period would help to establish that, but if you're trying to make it more timeless and generic, that would be a problem. Also, as a 62 year old man I'd be careful about trying to use contemporary teenage slang as I'd be likely to get it wrong and sound silly.

Answer (score 17):

Spend more time with your character outside the book.

- Have you ever seen those email questionnaires which go around
  occasionally? What's your favorite toothpaste, Coke or Pepsi, Beatles
  or Stones, ever been to Africa, what's under your bed, etc.? Get one
  of those, blank it out, and answer it *from the perspective of your
  character.*
- Cast your character. That is, in the movie, is your college    professor played by
  Morgan Freeman, Nathan Lane, Queen Latifah, Benedict Cumberbatch, or Judi
  Dench? Imagine the person talking. Really hear the voice.
- Write a letter to the editor from your character about something
  which the character is passionate about: global warming, gun control,
  abortion, dangling participles.
- Write an email/letter from your character to his or her best friend.
  Mother. Spouse. Send the character on vacation and write a whole email exchange.
- Nice bit of advice I saw somewhere: what does the character do in a
  quarrel?

Once you've spent some time establishing the person beyond his or her place in the plot, it will be easier to write in that voice. You may well have to go back multiple times for multiple people, and you may have to tell your beta readers and editors "Make sure my characters don't all sound the same."

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Lauren's list, here are a few things I do:

- Give each character a distinct background.  Some possible elements to vary are geography, culture, ethnicity, education, age, friends, family.  Each of these can affect a character's vocabulary, grammar, and general attitude toward the people and world around them.  Even in the same family, age and birth order vary.
- Give each character a definite personal history, with several significant events in their recent past.  Their history will affect their general attitude.  The recent past will put potentially useful joys, problems, and conflicts into their minds.
- If the characters already know each other before the story begins, know the significant events of their relationship, especially their recent interactions.  Write a conversation between them from a week, a month, or a year before the story starts.  Have one character describe an interaction between two other characters (perhaps witnessed from far enough away that the interaction can't be heard).
- Interview your characters.  [Here's how I do it](http://dalewriting.dale.emery.name/2008/09/interviews/), with links to some example interviews.  These interviews really helped me to understand each character's psychology and attitudes.

You don't need to include any of this in the story, but the better you know your characters as individuals, with individual histories and individual relationships, the better you will be able to give them individual voices.

Comment: +1 This was a fantastic addition to Lauren's answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: +1 for interviewing characters. I find this the single greatest tool in character development. Not only does it help with finding voice, it also let's me find character motivations and quirks without making conscious choices about them, which I think gives a much more natural, less contrived feel to them.

Answer (score 6):

I think speech idiosyncrasies are a part of distinguishing characters from each other, but they are, more than anything, stylistic, writerly flourishes. Conan Doyle didn't define Sherlock Holmes's voice by excessive use of stock phrases. Sure, Holmes utters some choice expressions like, "You know my methods", but those are few and ornamental. What defines Holmes is the hyper-rational nature of his speech patter, which is a direct representation of his intellect: of his character. He speaks the way he does because he *needs* to speak that way because he needs to think that way to solve crimes with efficiency. It's a matter of necessity owing to Conan Doyle's understanding of his character's wants and needs.

I think it boils down to that awareness of necessity. That is what creates unique characters and distinguishable dialogue.

To understand those root desires and motivations, ask yourself these questions:

> - What does my character want/need?
> - What is my character willing to do to get it?

Variations on those questions, such as can be fleshed out using the very useful exercises suggested in other answers, will help you develop the answers to those two primary questions.

Once you know what your character truly wants, you will know how to phrase dialogue to communicate that want, effectively creating a new manner of speech distinct from your own. As an example: how does a 5-year-old respond to the question "Where are the cookies?" Well, that depends. Does the kid want to avoid punishment? Does she want to put the blame on her big brother who is mean to her? Does she, for some asinine reason, feel compelled to tell the truth about eating the cookies? You are less likely to sound like yourself in answering the cookie question if you understand what specifically your character wants to accomplish with her speech. This may sound simplistic, but the ardor comes in letting the question of necessity guide every dialogue passage.

Characters, unlike real people, speak for a reason. As readers we expect this. We expect to glean personality traits through dialogue. As a writer, understanding that readers are searching for this makes our job easier. We don't have to convince our reader to analyze our character in the same way that we might have to convince a love interest to take a fancy for us. We have only to understand a character and to express their desires in speech and the reader will do the rest.

NB: Sherlock Holmes never once utters the phrase "Elementary, my dear Watson". The closest he comes is in *The Crooked Man* where he responds to one of Watson's congratulations with, simply, "Elementary". FWIW.

Comment: Side note: Sure, "Elementary my dear Watson" was from the movies, not the original books. Likewise the inverness cape.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the literary world goes overboard in claiming every character must sound like a totally different "narrative voice or so distinguishable. While certainly any accents, individual quirks, or personalities should come into play, when it comes to POV or beliefs, there's no reason we can't have three characters with similar viewpoints on a political or social context. Especially in contemporary fiction based on the reality of a friendship circle where we often have a group of anti-war activists or something like that. I've found some publishers and agents exhaustingly ridiculous about insisting characters in a novel sound too much alike, and it turns out they are referring more to their individual beliefs than their characterization. As if three people in a room simply need to always have some form of conflict of interest. It's unrealistic. I think this needs to be addressed deeper.

Comment: Sure. If I read a story about 4 close friends, I wouldn't be at all surprised if they were all, say, Republicans. It would be silly to say that as half of Americans are Democrats, that in a group of 4 friends 2 should be Republicans and 2 should be Democrats. In real life people often associate with those who agree with them. A writer could, of course, have one person with radically different beliefs in a group to create conflict, but that's probably less realistic rather than more. But the opposite extreme is for all the characters to be exactly alike.